# blender python: evaluate extruded curve points

Tags: python, add-on, bezier-curves, mathematics

I need to find coordinates of points extruded from blender's bezier curve **with python**. All I know right now is how to evaluate each point on the curve([mathutils.geometry.interpolate_bezier](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.interpolate_bezier)) but I don't know how to find the perpendicular vector with Spline's tilt.

[image: explanation]

Basically, I need to find a perpendicular vector with the original vector and tilt in each curve vertex. How do I do that in python?

So far I've only gotten the spline points but not the extrusion, here:

```py
import bpy
import mathutils
interp = mathutils.geometry.interpolate_bezier

class DummyOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.get_bezier"
    bl_label = "Extract Bezier Points"

    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        dat = ob.data
        bzp = dat.splines[0].bezier_points
        points=interp(bzp[0].co, bzp[0].handle_right, bzp[1].handle_left, bzp[1].co, dat.resolution_u+1)
        print(f"So far I can only extract this data:\n{dat.resolution_u},\nCurve points:")
        for p in points:
            print(p)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(DummyOp)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DummyOp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.object.get_bezier()
```

[image]

Comment: I know **this** -> `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH', keep_original=False)` method exists, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution without using bpy.ops. I will use this method for now

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`object.to_mesh()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh):

```py
>>> curve_ob = bpy.context.scene.objects['MyCurve']
>>> me = curve_ob.to_mesh()
>>> me.vertices[0].co
Vector((0.0, -1.0, -0.6200000047683716))
```

This allocates a mesh object specifically for the prupose of being manipulated using Python. You can then free this extra memory with [`object.to_mesh_clear()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh_clear).